# My tikzpicture does not compile!

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, overleaf

I am trying to compile my pdf while using Latex (in Overleaf) and even though it compiled just fine yesterday evening, ever since yesterday night I haven't been able to compile it. After I read the banner that appeared, I reached the conclusion that the problem was a tikzpicture that I'd added (even though yesterday it appeared just fine). I have used the following packages in total:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {c:/user/Desktop/images/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}
```

and then for my graph I have this:

```
$$
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,1) -- (3,0) -- (0,3) -- (1,1);
\draw [dashed] (0,0) -- (0,3);
\draw [dashed] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\node at (0,0)[below left]{$(0,0)$};
\node at (1,1)[left]{$(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$};
\node at (1,1)[below]{D}
\node at (0,3)[above]{$(0,1)$};
\node at (3,0)[below right]{$(1,0)$};
\draw[->] (3/2,3/4) -- (3/2,-1/2);
\node at (3/2,-1/2)[below]{$y=\frac{1-x}{2}$};
\draw[->] (3/4,3/2) -- (-1/2,3/2);
\node at (-1/2,3/2)[left]{$y=-2x+1$};
\draw[->] (3/2,3/2) -- (2,3/2);
\node at (2,3/2)[right]{$y=1-x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
$$
```

I can't not include this in my assignment. Do I have to write it somehow else for it to be compiled (even if it worked before)? Are there any other sites that I can use that will be able to compile this along with about 5 pages of the rest of my assignment? The problem is...I've tried just compiling this in hopes of screenshooting it and then adding it as a picture instead but the program can't even compile this alone! What am I doing wrong? I swear this wasn't a problem before, but now I can't do anything about it and my assignment is due in 5 hours...

Comment: please don't post disconnected fragments, post a small complete document that shows the problem. (tikzpictures are not usually placed in math so `$$` is not usually used here)

Comment: The error message here is very clear and pinpoints the exact error. Always read the log file.

Comment: I don't understand, I'm sorry... I'm new to Latex and very stressed right now. The error that appears is this: "Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a LaTeX error, or a large number of high-res images or complicated diagrams." and the best I could understand was that one of my two graphs took a toll on the program. The file contains purely text and some integrals. And if I remove this extract I've provided, that's when it does compile. But then again, when I do try to compile just this graph in a new project it does not compile..

Comment: the timeout  is probably unrelated to the code you have shown, this is a simple syntax error you forgot ` ;` at the end of one of the lines and so the tikz code gives an error saying a `;` is missing.  As always you should provide a complete small test file and show the log that you get. No one can debug disconnected fragments

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. Thanks again.

Comment: nothing to apologise for:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,1) -- (3,0) -- (0,3) -- (1,1);
\draw [dashed] (0,0) -- (0,3);
\draw [dashed] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\node at (0,0)[below left]{$(0,0)$};
\node at (1,1)[left]{$(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$};
\node at (1,1)[below]{D}
\node at (0,3)[above]{$(0,1)$};
\node at (3,0)[below right]{$(1,0)$};
\draw[->] (3/2,3/4) -- (3/2,-1/2);
\node at (3/2,-1/2)[below]{$y=\frac{1-x}{2}$};
\draw[->] (3/4,3/2) -- (-1/2,3/2);
\node at (-1/2,3/2)[left]{$y=-2x+1$};
\draw[->] (3/2,3/2) -- (2,3/2);
\node at (2,3/2)[right]{$y=1-x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Gives the error message

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.14 \node
           at (0,3)[above]{$(0,1)$};
?
```

Because there is a `;` missing from the end of line 13. There should be `;` after `{D}`.

Comment: Thank you! That message is much clearer, I had indeed missed a semicolon that I could not see. The error that appeared for me was "Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a LaTeX error, or a large number of high-res images or complicated diagrams." and it wasn't very clear. Thanky you for helping me fix the problem!

Comment: @Tita if you had made a small document such as this to generate an example for your question then you would have seen exactly this error in overleaf.

Comment: At least in some version of Ti*k*Z  `\draw.... \node{}` will give the error and, when trying to continue, it will go into an infinite loop. See https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1025 --- it's fixed in the current release, but I do not know which version is using the overleaf project...